# RoR, chapter 5, expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us") to return true, got false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, and I am doing the Chapter 5 exercises. Can someone please explain why this test is failing?

Here is spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

#  let(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

  subject { page }

  shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: heading) }
    it { should have_title(full_title(page_title)) }
  end

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    let(:heading) { 'Sample App' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like  "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    let(:heading) { 'Help' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like  "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_title('| Help') }
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before { visit about_path }

    let(:heading) { 'About' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like  "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_title('| About Us') }
  end

  describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    let(:heading) { 'Contact' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like  "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_title('| Contact') }
  end

  it "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('About Us'))
    click_link "Help"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Help'))
    click_link "Contact"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Contact'))
    click_link "Home"
    click_link "Sign up now!"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sign up'))
    click_link "sample app"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sample App'))
  end

end
```

Here is app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb

```
<h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>
      The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
      is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
      with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
      is the sample application for the tutorial.
    </p>
```

My test rspec spec/

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages should have the right links on the layout
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title(full_title('About us'))
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About us") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.11 seconds
13 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:54 # Static pages should have the right links on the layout
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain why this test is failing?

The gist your problem seems to be that the full [`title`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp) of the page is:

`"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About us"` and **not** `"About us"`.

Which is what the test-suite tells you. I think you might have expected the `base_title` to be "empty". (The topmost `let(:base_title)`)?

Comment: Excuse me, I'm newbie in RoR, and in this case I don't understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial? https://github.com/keokent/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb Is missing `let(:base_title)`.

Comment: By the way, though test doesn't pass :(, web-application works, and on the About page I have a title "Ruby on Rails tutorial Sample App" like on other pages.

Comment: I was not attentive because not correctly wrote the code. Now it works correctly. Thanks, Philipp.

Comment: @Gvyntyk glad to hear you sticking with it. Sorry for not replying.